# Java program that indicates if the input string is a valid password

Tags: passwords, pseudocode

Hi looking for help on a project, I need Java program that indicates if the input string is a valid password. Requirements are it should be at between 8 and 15 characters in length, it should contain at least one uppercase character and it should contain at least one digit (number). Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use Regular Expression Class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String passwd = "Asscw1q2";
String pattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$";
System.out.println(passwd.matches(pattern));
```

(?=.*[0-9])- atLeast 1 digit

(?=.*[A-Z])- atLeast 1 upperCase

.{8,15}-  8 <= Length <= 15

prints true if the pattern matches.